# How to undo last drawn box on Vaadin canvas?

Tags: java, arrays, canvas, vaadin

I have a canvas where I can draw bounding boxes on a canvas in Vaadin, and I am trying to implement an undo function whereby the last drawn box will both be removed from the array and on the canvas. In the undoLast method (which is found in Canvas.java and called in the MainLayout.java), I remove the last element of the array (arrayBoxes which contains all the boxes drawn), and attempt to clear the entire canvas before redrawing the ones left in the array. However, I am getting an array error.

MainLayout:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.backend;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.HtmlImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H2;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.NativeButton;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.Theme;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.lumo.Lumo;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.BoundingBox;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.Canvas;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.CanvasRenderingContext2D;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.MousePosition;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The main layout contains the header with the navigation buttons, and the
 * child views below that.
 */

@HtmlImport("frontend://styles/shared-styles.html")
@Route("")
@Theme(Lumo.class)
public class MainLayout extends VerticalLayout {

    private CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx;
    private Canvas canvas;
    ArrayList<MousePosition> mousePosArray = Canvas.getMousePosArray();
    ArrayList<BoundingBox> bb = Canvas.getArrayBoxes();
    public static int count = 0;


    public MainLayout() {

        VerticalLayout footerLayout = new VerticalLayout();

        H2 title = new H2("Annotation UI");
        title.addClassName("main-layout__title");

        canvas = new Canvas(1580, 700);

        ctx = canvas.getContext();

        Div buttons = new Div();
        buttons.add(new NativeButton("Save Annotations"));
        buttons.add(new NativeButton("Previous Picture"));
        buttons.add(new NativeButton("Next Picture"));
        buttons.add(new NativeButton("Undo", e -> Canvas.undoLast()));
        buttons.add(new NativeButton("Clear Canvas",
                e -> ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1580, 700)));

        add(canvas, buttons);

        Label label = new Label();
        canvas.addComponent(label);
        add(label);

//        HorizontalLayout fieldLayout = new HorizontalLayout();

        TextField boxname = new TextField();
        boxname.setLabel("Box Name:");
        boxname.setPlaceholder("Enter bounding box name");

        TextField boxcategory = new TextField();
        boxcategory.setLabel("Box Category:");
        boxcategory.setPlaceholder("Enter bounding box category");
        add(boxname, boxcategory);

        Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
        submitButton.addClickListener(event -> {
            if (count == 0){
                count = count + 1;
            }
            bb.get(count - 1).setName(boxname.getValue());
            bb.get(count - 1).setBoxcategory(boxcategory.getValue());
            count = count + 1;
            boxname.clear();
            boxcategory.clear();

                System.out.println(bb.toString());


        });
        add(submitButton);

        canvas.addMouseMoveListener(() -> label.setText("Coordinates: " + mousePosArray.get(0)));

        }
    }
```

Canvas.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.HasSize;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.HasStyle;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element;
import com.vaadin.flow.dom.ElementFactory;
import com.vaadin.flow.shared.Registration;
import elemental.json.JsonObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Canvas component that you can draw shapes and images on. It's a Java wrapper
 * for the
 * <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API">HTML5
 * canvas</a>.
 * <p>
 * Use {@link #getContext()} to get API for rendering shapes and images on the
 * canvas.
 * <p>
 */
@Tag("canvas")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Canvas extends Component implements HasStyle, HasSize {

    private static CanvasRenderingContext2D context;
    private Element element;
    private boolean isDrawing = false;
    private boolean mouseIsDown = false;
    private double endX;
    private double endY;

    public static ArrayList <BoundingBox> arrayBoxes = new ArrayList<BoundingBox>();
    public static ArrayList <MousePosition> mousePosArray = new ArrayList<MousePosition>();
    private List<Runnable> mouseMoveListeners = new ArrayList<>(0);

    public static ArrayList<BoundingBox> getArrayBoxes() {
        return arrayBoxes;
    }

    public static ArrayList<MousePosition> getMousePosArray() {
        return mousePosArray;
    }

    public static void setMousePosArray(ArrayList<MousePosition> mousePosArray) {
        Canvas.mousePosArray = mousePosArray;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new canvas component with the given size.
     * <p>
     * Use the API provided by {@link #getContext()} to render graphics on the
     * canvas.
     * <p>
     * The width and height parameters will be used for the canvas' coordinate
     * system. They will determine the size of the component in pixels, unless
     * you explicitly set the component's size with {@link #setWidth(String)} or
     * {@link #setHeight(String)}.
     *
//     * @param width
//     *            the width of the canvas
//     * @param height
//     *            the height of the canvas
//     */

    public Registration addMouseMoveListener(Runnable listener) {
        mouseMoveListeners.add(listener);
        return () -> mouseMoveListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public Canvas(int width, int height) {

        context = new CanvasRenderingContext2D(this);

        element = getElement();
        element.getStyle().set("border", "1px solid");

        getElement().setAttribute("width", String.valueOf(width));
        getElement().setAttribute("height", String.valueOf(height));

        element.addEventListener("mousedown", event -> {  // Retrieve Starting Position on MouseDown

            Element boundingBoxResult = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult);

            JsonObject evtData = event.getEventData();

            double xBox = evtData.getNumber("event.x");
            double yBox = evtData.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-x", String.format("%f", xBox));
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-y", String.format("%f", yBox));

            BoundingBox newBox = new BoundingBox("","", xBox, yBox, 0.0, 0.0);
            arrayBoxes.add(newBox);

            isDrawing = true;
            mouseIsDown=true;

            mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");


        element.addEventListener("mouseup", event -> {  // Draw Box on MouseUp

            Element boundingBoxResult2 = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult2);

            JsonObject evtData2 = event.getEventData();

            endX = evtData2.getNumber("event.x");
            endY = evtData2.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-x", String.format("%f", endX));
            boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-y", String.format("%f", endY));

            double xcoordi = 0;
            double ycoordi = 0;
            double boxWidth = 0;
            double boxHeight = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++) {
                arrayBoxes.get(i).setWidth(endX, arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi);
                arrayBoxes.get(i).setHeight(endY, arrayBoxes.get(i).ycoordi);
                xcoordi = arrayBoxes.get(i).getXcoordi();
                ycoordi = arrayBoxes.get(i).getYcoordi();
                boxWidth = arrayBoxes.get(i).getWidth();
                boxHeight = arrayBoxes.get(i).getHeight();
            }

                mouseIsDown=false;

                context.beginPath();
                context.setStrokeStyle("green");
                context.setLineWidth(2);
                context.strokeRect(xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth, boxHeight);
                context.stroke();
                context.fill();

            System.out.println(arrayBoxes.toString());
            mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");

        element.addEventListener("mousemove", event -> {  // Retrieve Mouse Position when Moving

                JsonObject mousePos = event.getEventData();

                double mouseX = mousePos.getNumber("event.x");
                double mouseY = mousePos.getNumber("event.y");

                MousePosition currentPos = new MousePosition(mouseX, mouseY);
                mousePosArray.add(0, currentPos);
                setMousePosArray(mousePosArray);
            mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

     }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");

    }


    public static void undoLast() {
        if (arrayBoxes.size() > 0) {
            arrayBoxes.remove(arrayBoxes.size() - 1);
        }
//        System.out.println(arrayBoxes.toString());
        System.out.println(arrayBoxes.get(0).toString());
        System.out.println(arrayBoxes.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++){
            context.clearRect(0, 0, 1580, 700);
            context.beginPath();
            context.setStrokeStyle("limegreen");
            context.setLineWidth(2);
            context.strokeRect(arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).ycoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxWidth, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxHeight);
            context.fill();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Gets the context for rendering shapes and images in the canvas.
     * <p>
     * It is a Java wrapper for the <a href=
     * "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D">same
     * client-side API</a>.
     *
     * @return the 2D rendering context of this canvas
     */
    public CanvasRenderingContext2D getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> Canvas has an internal coordinate system that it uses for
     * drawing, and it uses the width and height provided in the constructor.
     * This coordinate system is independent of the component's size. Changing
     * the component's size with this method may scale/stretch the rendered
     * graphics.
     */
    @Override
    public void setWidth(String width) {
        HasSize.super.setWidth(width);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> Canvas has an internal coordinate system that it uses for
     * drawing, and it uses the width and height provided in the constructor.
     * This coordinate system is independent of the component's size. Changing
     * the component's size with this method may scale/stretch the rendered
     * graphics.
     */
    @Override
    public void setHeight(String height) {
        HasSize.super.setHeight(height);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> Canvas has an internal coordinate system that it uses for
     * drawing, and it uses the width and height provided in the constructor.
     * This coordinate system is independent of the component's size. Changing
     * the component's size with this method may scale/stretch the rendered
     * graphics.
     */
    @Override
    public void setSizeFull() {
        HasSize.super.setSizeFull();
    }

    public void addComponent(Label label) {
    }
}
```

CanvasRenderingContext2D.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.backend.MainLayout;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The context for rendering shapes and images on a canvas.
 * <p>
 * This is a Java wrapper for the <a href=
 * "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D">same
 * client-side API</a>.
 */
public class CanvasRenderingContext2D {

    private Canvas canvas;
    public static ArrayList<BoundingBox> arrayBoxes = new ArrayList<BoundingBox>();

    protected CanvasRenderingContext2D(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void setFillStyle(String fillStyle) {
        setProperty("fillStyle", fillStyle);
    }

    public void setStrokeStyle(String strokeStyle) {
        setProperty("strokeStyle", strokeStyle);
    }

    public void setLineWidth(double lineWidth) {
        setProperty("lineWidth", lineWidth);
    }

    public void setFont(String font) {
        setProperty("font", font);
    }

    public void arc(double x, double y, double radius, double startAngle,
            double endAngle, boolean antiClockwise) {
        callJsMethod("arc", x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, antiClockwise);
    }

    public void beginPath() {
        callJsMethod("beginPath");
    }

    public void clearRect(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        callJsMethod("clearRect", x, y, width, height);
        Canvas.arrayBoxes.clear();
        System.out.println(arrayBoxes.toString());
        MainLayout.count = 0;
    }

    public void closePath() {
        callJsMethod("closePath");
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the image from the given location and draws it on the canvas.
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> The drawing will happen asynchronously after the browser has
     * received the image.
     * 
     * @param src
     *            the url of the image to draw
     * @param x
     *            the x-coordinate of the top-left corner of the image
     * @param y
     *            the y-coordinate of the top-left corner of the image
     */
    public void drawImage(String src, double x, double y) {
        runScript(String.format(
                "var zwKqdZ = new Image();" + "zwKqdZ.onload = function () {"
                        + "$0.getContext('2d').drawImage(zwKqdZ, %s, %s);};"
                        + "zwKqdZ.src='%s';",
                x, y, src));
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the image from the given location and draws it on the canvas.
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> The drawing will happen asynchronously after the browser has
     * received the image.
     * 
     * @param src
     *            the url of the image to draw
     * @param x
     *            the x-coordinate of the top-left corner of the image
     * @param y
     *            the y-coordinate of the top-left corner of the image
     * @param width
     *            the width for the image
     * @param height
     *            the height for the image
     */
    public void drawImage(String src, double x, double y, double width,
            double height) {
        runScript(String.format("var zwKqdZ = new Image();"
                + "zwKqdZ.onload = function () {"
                + "$0.getContext('2d').drawImage(zwKqdZ, %s, %s, %s, %s);};"
                + "zwKqdZ.src='%s';", x, y, width, height, src));
    }

    public void fill() {
        callJsMethod("fill");
    }

    public void fillRect(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        callJsMethod("fillRect", x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void fillText(String text, double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("fillText", text, x, y);
    }

    public void lineTo(double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("lineTo", x, y);
    }

    public void moveTo(double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("moveTo", x, y);
    }

    public void rect(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        callJsMethod("rect", x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void restore() {
        callJsMethod("restore");
    }

    public void rotate(double angle) {
        callJsMethod("rotate", angle);
    }

    public void save() {
        callJsMethod("save");
    }

    public void scale(double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("scale", x, y);
    }

    public void stroke() {
        callJsMethod("stroke");
    }

    public void strokeRect(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        callJsMethod("strokeRect", x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void strokeText(String text, double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("strokeText", text, x, y);
    }

    public void translate(double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("translate", x, y);
    }

    protected void setProperty(String propertyName, Serializable value) {
        runScript(String.format("$0.getContext('2d').%s='%s'", propertyName,
                value));
    }

    /**
     * Runs the given js so that the execution order works with callJsMethod().
     * Any $0 in the script will refer to the canvas element.
     */
    private void runScript(String script) {
        canvas.getElement().getNode().runWhenAttached(
                // This structure is needed to make the execution order work
                // with Element.callFunction() which is used in callJsMethod()
                ui -> ui.getInternals().getStateTree().beforeClientResponse(
                        canvas.getElement().getNode(),
                        context -> ui.getPage().executeJavaScript(script,
                                canvas.getElement())));
    }

    protected void callJsMethod(String methodName, Serializable... parameters) {
        canvas.getElement().callFunction("getContext('2d')." + methodName,
                parameters);
    }

}
```

BoundingBox.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

public class BoundingBox {

    public double xcoordi = 0;
    public double ycoordi = 0;
    public double boxWidth = 0;
    public double boxHeight = 0;
    public String boxname;
    public String boxcategory;

    public BoundingBox(String boxname, String boxcategory, double xcoordi, double ycoordi, double boxWidth, double boxHeight) {
        this.boxname = boxname;
        this.boxcategory = boxcategory;
        this.xcoordi = xcoordi;
        this.ycoordi = ycoordi;
        this.boxWidth = boxWidth;
        this.boxHeight = boxHeight;
    }

    public String getBoxName() {
        return boxname;
    }

    public void setName(String boxname) {
        this.boxname = boxname;
    }

    public String getBoxcategory() {
        return boxcategory;
    }

    public void setBoxcategory(String boxcategory) {
        this.boxcategory = boxcategory;
    }

    public double getXcoordi() {
        return xcoordi;
    }

    public void setXcoordi(double xcoordi) {
        this.xcoordi = xcoordi;
    }

    public double getYcoordi() {
        return ycoordi;
    }

    public void setYcoordi(double ycoordi) {
        this.ycoordi = ycoordi;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return boxWidth;
    }

    public void setWidth(double endX, double xcoordi) {
        boxWidth = endX - xcoordi;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return boxHeight;
    }

    public void setHeight(double endY, double ycoordi) {
        boxHeight = endY - ycoordi;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "Name=" + boxname +
                ", Class=" + boxcategory +
                ", X=" + xcoordi +
                ", Y=" + ycoordi +
                ", Width=" + boxWidth +
                ", Height=" + boxHeight +
                '}';
    }
}
```

MousePosition.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

public class MousePosition {

    public double mouseX;
    public double mouseY;

    public MousePosition(double mouseX, double mouseY) {
        this.mouseX = mouseX;
        this.mouseY = mouseY;
    }

    public double getMouseX() {
        return mouseX;
    }

    public void setMouseX(double mouseX) {
        this.mouseX = mouseX;
    }

    public double getMouseY() {
        return mouseY;
    }

    public void setMouseY(double mouseY) {
        this.mouseY = mouseY;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "X = " + mouseX +
                ", Y = " + mouseY;
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
[qtp1975873209-21] ERROR com.vaadin.flow.server.DefaultErrorHandler - 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.Canvas.undoLast(Canvas.java:191)
    at com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.backend.MainLayout.lambda$new$9b1b5227$1(MainLayout.java:67)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:133)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:327)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$5ee67f2b$1(ComponentEventBus.java:191)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:379)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:379)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:59)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:64)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:377)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$0(ServerRpcHandler.java:367)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:367)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:309)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1487)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:300)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You seem to clear the canvas for each rect you draw in the undo method, which means only the last one would be visible.

That being said, it sounds like you had some other error, could you provide the stack trace you get? It is useful for determining where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: @Tazavoo I have added the stack trace, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your undo method, you have this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 1580, 700);
    context.beginPath();
    context.setStrokeStyle("limegreen");
    context.setLineWidth(2);
    context.strokeRect(arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).ycoordi, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxWidth, arrayBoxes.get(i).boxHeight);
    context.fill();
}
```

Your `context.clearRect()` function contains the line

```
Canvas.arrayBoxes.clear();
```

Which removes all items from the `arrayBoxes` array. Therefore you get an exception at the end of the for loop when you try executing `arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi` etc.